# How can I write TMP code of below question C++

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, template-meta-programming

I am quite new to TMP world though I can easily understand the code but have problem writing new. I was given below question which I couldn't solve. Can someone help me understand how could I have done this.

Below is the description of the question

```cpp
template<int... Xs> struct Vector;
```

It can be used  like this:

```cpp
Vector<1,2,3>
```

We want to write a function that takes multiple vectors, and zips then *.i.e. given input

```cpp
Vector<1,2,3>, Vector<2,3,4>, Vector<3,4,5>
```

produce:

```cpp
Vector<6,24,60>
```

A common way to implement this kind of computation statically is with a metafunction

```cpp
template <typename... Vectors>
struct zip 
{
    using type = XXXX;
}
```

where XXXX is the logic of the zip. We could verify like so:

```cpp
static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        zip<Vector<1, 2, 3>, Vector<2, 3, 4>, Vector<3, 4, 5>>::type, 
        Vector<6, 24, 60>>::value);
```

I would like to know, how to complete this logic, Thanks.

Comment: You retyped the attached image. So you could delete the image (formatted text is better than the image). Please be more specific in your question. What specifically didn't you understand?

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for the suggestion. Removed the image.

Comment: Could you also write, what you understand about the question and the concepts behind it and what not, and where you are stuck, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way to implement this `zip` metafunction in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) using [partial template specializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

```cpp
template <int...> struct Vector;

template <typename...>
struct zip;

template <int... Is>
struct zip<Vector<Is...>> {
    using type = Vector<Is...>;
};

template <int... Is, int... Js, typename... Vectors>
struct zip<Vector<Is...>, Vector<Js...>, Vectors...> {
    using type = typename zip<Vector<(Is * Js)...>, Vectors...>::type;
};
```

[Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/odGYdWdv5)

Answer (score 2):

You have chosen a rather non-trivial problem as your first attempt at template metaprogramming. Anyway, here's my take:

```
template<int... Xs> struct Vector;

template <int... Xs>
constexpr std::size_t vectorSize(Vector<Xs...>*) {
    return sizeof...(Xs);
}

template <typename V>
constexpr std::size_t vectorSize() {
    return vectorSize(static_cast<V*>(nullptr));
}

template <std::size_t I, int... Xs>
constexpr int getVal(Vector<Xs...>*) {
    return std::get<I>(std::make_tuple(Xs...));
}

template <std::size_t I, typename V>
constexpr int getVal() {
    return getVal<I>(static_cast<V*>(nullptr));
}

template <std::size_t I, typename... Vs>
constexpr int makeProd() {
    return (getVal<I, Vs>() * ...);
}

template <typename... Vs, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto zipHelper(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> Vector<makeProd<Is, Vs...>()...>;

template <typename... Vs>
struct zip 
{
    static constexpr std::size_t size =
      vectorSize<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Vs...>>>();
    static_assert(((vectorSize<Vs>() == size) && ...));

    using type = decltype(zipHelper<Vs...>(std::make_index_sequence<size>{}));
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qG67T8WEx)